# Microsoft Access: How do I enter a comma in text filtering?

Tags: ms-access, filter, full-text-search

I want to do a text filter in Access searching for a pattern that includes a comma. But when I used , or put it in double quotes, Access gave me an error.
How do I search for text containing the comma character? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise: what is the code you use for filtering? What is the field you are filtering? It is even a text field? What error did Access give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your question is quite unclear. What do you mean by "text filter"? What do you mean by "searching for a pattern"? What kind of error message do you get?

For my answers below, I'm assuming that the data you want to search on is saved in a text field.

SQL allows you to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CompanyName WHERE CompanyName LIKE '*,*'
```

If you're using the Access form filter property your filter should look like this:

```
strFilter = "CompanyName LIKE '*,*'"
```